# Error after going live with Express Checkout for Digital Goods

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

After having everything working against paypal sandbox, I switched over URLs and Credentials to go live using Express Checkout for Digital Goods.  However, every attempt to make a purchase results in this message when the user is redirected to paypal:

> We are unable to complete your request at this time. Please try again
>   later. We apologize for the inconvenience.

I've tried a number of 'solutions' to this problem, but none are working for my specific issue.  I'm including some details below, but please let me know if there's anything else I can provide to help in solving this problem.

- Url for requests:  https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
- Redirect Url (with example token):  https://www.paypal.com/incontext?token=EC%2d50D36426BB652071N&useraction=commit
- Parameters I'm Passing

```
  def paramData = [
    'USER': paypalUsername,
    'PWD': pwd,
    'SIGNATURE': signature,
    'METHOD':'SetExpressCheckout',
    'VERSION':'65.1',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' : '1.00',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE':'USD',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT':'1.00',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION':'Sale',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0':'Some Product',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0':'Some Product',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0':'1.00',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0':'1',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0':'Digital',
    'REQCONFIRMSHIPPING':'0',
    'NOSHIPPING':'1',
    'RETURNURL' : 'http://mydomain.com/return',
    'CANCELURL' : 'http://mydomain.com/cancel'
    ]
```

- Javascript I'm using to attach trigger to paypal button: 
  `var dg1 = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: "buyStart1" });`
- And yes, I have a verified, business account
- Also, the response from the SetExpressCheckout call that happens before the redirect looks like this:

```
TOKEN=EC%2d50D36426BB652071N&TIMESTAMP=2012%2d08%2d02T14%3a57%3a33Z&CORREL
ATIONID=93da36285a4ae&ACK=Success&VERSION=65%2e1&BUILD=3386080
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this error several times over the years, which typically resulted in either an internal PayPal problem or something they needed to fix on their side.  I recommend a quick call to Paypal merchant support, they should be able to fix it quickly, or at least tell you where the problem lies.

Comment: Good to know... We've submitted a ticket online but haven't received a response yet.  We'll try calling them.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: finally able to call them and they found the issue - my token in the redirect url was being encoded twice, causing it to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I can't add a comment to Jimmyb's answer - but the answer really was to call PayPal.

I've just gotten off the phone to them and have been told that I need to apply to the sales team to have Digital Goods functionality enabled on my account. The sales team is out of the office at the moment so I'll find out for sure tomorrow but it's sounding hopeful.